# Access is denied connecting to SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, forms-authentication

I've deployed my project to Azure and my login page loads. When I attempt to login, it hangs for a moment and returns an "Access is denied" error. I've double and triple checked my connection string and it matches the one provided by Azure.

I've deployed to Azure in the past but it's been a while. Is there something I need to do in order to make my DB accessible? I read a couple articles about similar problems people had with remote connections. It involved turning on remote connection accessibility in SSMS, but I don't see that being the case in my situation as it's not being accessed thru Sql Server.

Are there modifications I must make to my DB to make it accessible on Azure?

Here's my error:
[image]

EDIT - I am using forms authentication for user handling if it makes a difference.

Comment: firewall + endpoint port

Comment: Check the application login by which you are trying to connect and see if it has permissions

Comment: I've already allowed my IP and gotten the message "The current IP address already has a firewall rule. You should be able to connect..." Can you elaborate a bit on "endpoint port"?

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Do you mean link the web app to the database? I've created a linked resource between the two and it's displaying my app in the DB dashboard.

Comment: On the sql azure database settings/firewall page there should be a setting called something like "allow access from azure services". Make sure that is set to true. If it wasn't, give it a few minutes and restart your Web site before trying again.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that your Azure SQL Database is not configured to accept connections from the service you are trying to connect.

You have to Enable `Windows Azure Services` to connect to your Azure SQL Database Server.

To achieve that, navigate to your Azure SQL Database Dashboard and click on Manage Allowed IP Addresses, as shown bellow:
[image]

Then On this new page, make sure that Windows Azure Services are enabled (YES):
[image]

Comment: Azure services are already allowed, I double checked. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that I didn't have the database and the app service in the same location.  One was in Australia East while the other was in Australia South East.  I moved my app service to be in the same location as the DB and bingo. :)